# How can I construct a planar tangle, shaed or un-shaded, in LaTeX or Mathematica using the tikz package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, packages, tikz-knots

I have tried searching for tikz code regarding planar tangles and planar algebras online, but the code does not copy over accurately. I noticed that in these online sources, the package "mathfig" was mentioned. I googled mathfig package tikz, and learned that it is a package used to refer to graphics plotted using mathematica. That is where I am stuck. How can I create a planar tangle in either LaTeX directly, or how can I first create it in mathematica and then apply it in LaTeX with the tikz package?

Here is what I was able to get with just using the draw command and nodes:

```
$\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (2,2) circle (2.5cm);
\draw node[circle, draw, minimum size=.5cm] at (2.75, 1.75) {h};
\draw (2.75,2.10) -- (2.75,2.95);
\draw (3,1.9) -- (4.5,1.93);
\draw node[circle, draw, minimum size=.5cm] at (.5, 1.5) {f};
\draw (.6,1.25) -- (1.25,-0.35);
\draw (.6,1.25) -- (0,.5);
\draw (.6,1.25) -- (1,4.25);
\draw (.6,1.25) -- (0,3.5);
\draw node[circle, draw, minimum size=.5cm] at (2.75, 3.25) {g};
\draw (2.65,3.5) -- (2.65,4.5);
\end{tikzpicture}$
```

Question: How can I construct a planar tangle, shaed or un-shaded, in LaTeX or Mathematica using the tikz package? Do I just have to keep changing the positions of nodes and strings to get the tangle I want, or is there a more effective means of going about it? Also, any input on how to construct a planar in Mathematica so that I can use the "\mathfig" command to upload the Mathematica image of the Tangle into LaTeX would be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

There is a paper about planar algebras on the [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.1294) which has loads of such diagrams, all drawn in TikZ.

> **A planar algebra construction of the Haagerup subfactor**
>   Emily Peters
>   [Int. J. Math., 21, 987 (2010)](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0129167X10006380)
>   https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.1294

You can download the source of the article as gzipped TAR archive ([direct download](https://arxiv.org/e-print/0902.1294)).

I copied the first two diagrams out of the paper as a showcase:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  shaded/.style = {fill=red!10!blue!20!gray!30!white},
  Tbox/.style = {circle, draw, thick, fill=white, opaque},
  PAdefn/.style = {scale=.7,baseline},
}

\begin{document}

% Diagrams/SampleTangle.tex
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
  \clip (0,0) circle (3cm);

  \begin{scope}[shift=(10:1cm)] 
    \draw[shaded] (0,0)--(0:6cm)--(90:6cm)--(0,0);  
    \draw[shaded] (0,0) .. controls ++(180:2cm) and ++(-90:2cm) .. (0,0);
  \end{scope}

  \draw[shaded] (-150:1cm) -- (120:4cm) -- (180:4cm) -- (-150:1cm);
  \draw[shaded] (-150:1cm) -- (-120:4cm) -- (-60:4cm) -- (-150:1cm);

  \begin{scope}[shift=(10:1cm)] 
    \node at (0,0) [Tbox, inner sep=2mm] {};
    \node at (90:1.5cm) [Tbox, inner sep=2mm] {};
    \node at (-45:.7cm) {$\star$};
    \node at (120:1.6cm) {$\star$};
  \end{scope}
  \node at (-150:1cm) [Tbox, inner sep=2mm] {};
  \node at (-120:1.6cm) {$\star$};
  \node at (-30:2.7cm) {$\star$};

  \draw[very thick] (0,0) circle (3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}


% Diagrams/CompositionEG.tex
\[
  \begin{tikzpicture}[PAdefn]
    \clip (0,0) circle (3cm);

    \begin{scope}[shift=(10:1cm)]   
      \draw[shaded] (0,0)--(0:6cm)--(90:6cm)--(0,0);    
      \draw[shaded] (0,0) .. controls ++(180:2cm) and ++(-90:2cm) .. (0,0);
    \end{scope}

    \draw[shaded] (-150:1cm) -- (120:4cm) -- (180:4cm) -- (-150:1cm);
    \draw[shaded] (-150:1cm) -- (-120:4cm) -- (-60:4cm) -- (-150:1cm);

    \begin{scope}[shift=(10:1cm)]   
      \node at (0,0) [Tbox, inner sep=1.4mm] {\tiny{\textcolor{gray}{2}}};
      \node at (90:1.5cm) [Tbox, inner sep=1.4mm] {\tiny{\textcolor{gray}{1}}};
      \node at (-45:.7cm) {$\star$};
      \node at (120:1.6cm) {$\star$};
    \end{scope}
    \node at (-150:1cm) [Tbox, inner sep=1.4mm] {\tiny{\textcolor{gray}{3}}};
    \node at (-120:1.6cm) {$\star$};
    \node at (-30:2.7cm) {$\star$};

    \draw[very thick] (0,0) circle (3cm);

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \,
  \circ_{2}
  \,
  \begin{tikzpicture}[PAdefn]
    \clip (0,0) circle (2cm);

    \draw[shaded] (0:4cm)--(0,0)--(90:4cm);
    \draw[shaded] (180:4cm)--(180:2cm) .. controls ++(0:1cm) and ++(90:1cm) .. (270:2cm) -- (270:4cm);

    \node at (0,0) [Tbox, inner sep=2mm] {};

    \node at (-45:1.7cm) {$\star$};
    \node at (-45:.7cm) {$\star$};  

    \draw[very thick] (0,0) circle (2cm);

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \,
  =
  \,
  \begin{tikzpicture}[PAdefn]
    \clip (0,0) circle (3cm);

    \begin{scope}[shift=(10:1cm)]   
      \draw[shaded] (0:6cm)--(90:6cm)--(90:2cm) .. controls ++(-90:1cm) and ++(180:.5cm) .. (0:1cm)--(0:6cm);   
      \draw[shaded] (-135:.6cm) circle (.5cm);
    \end{scope}

    \draw[shaded] (-150:1cm) -- (120:4cm) -- (180:4cm) -- (-150:1cm);
    \draw[shaded] (-150:1cm) -- (-120:4cm) -- (-60:4cm) -- (-150:1cm);

    \begin{scope}[shift=(10:1cm)]   
      \node at (0:.8cm) [Tbox, inner sep=2mm] {};
      \node at (90:1.5cm) [Tbox, inner sep=2mm] {};
      \node at (-45:.9cm) {$\star$};
      \node at (120:1.6cm) {$\star$};
    \end{scope}
    \node at (-150:1cm) [Tbox, inner sep=2mm] {};
    \node at (-120:1.6cm) {$\star$};
    \node at (-30:2.7cm) {$\star$};

    \draw[very thick] (0,0) circle (3cm);

  \end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```